# Demo Account Branding: Override DocuSign_EmailResources

Tags: docusignapi

I uploaded a file DocuSign_EmailResources.xml to override the Master file and I do not my the changes. The [documentation](http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Quick%20Start%20-%20Account%20Branding.pdf) says that 'The ability to use the resource file option is **not 
normally enabled** for an account; contact your Account Manager or DocuSign Support for more 
information about enabling this option in your account'.

Before we update our production, we would like test on our demo account using SOAP API. I just want to add a link to the Email text. When I try this through the API, the link is disabled in the email as it is being formatted by the server side program.

Is there any setting that I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the docs, "The Account Branding feature is only supported in DocuSign Business, Enterprise, System Automated (SA), and DocuSign for Real Estate plans." Is your demo account one of those types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see (and access) the **Resources** tab when Editing a Brand Profile in the DocuSign web console, then this should mean that "the ability to use the resource file..." is indeed already enabled for your account.

[image: Edit Brand - Resource Files]

The Email Resource file is quite lengthy, and is divided into various sections -- each section being the email template that's used for a specific type of email that DocuSign sends.  So, for example, if you wanted to modify the contents of the "signing invitation" email that DocuSign sends to a recipient when it's their turn to sign, you'd modify contents within the ***Envelope Activation*** section of the Email Resource File.  Changes applied to other sections of the resource file would not impact/affect the signing invitation email.  If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you review the Email Resource File Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign%20System%20Default%20Email%20Formats.pdf) to ensure that you've modified the correct section of the resource file for the type of email that you intend to effect.

Also, keep in mind that each Email Resource File applies to a specific (single) Brand.  So, if you have multiple Brands within your account, make sure that you're modifying the Email Resource File for the Brand that's used for the Envelopes where you expect/want customized email content.

Comment: Thank you for referring to Envelope Activation.